# What is the number of ring isomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}^n$ to $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

Yesterday, I faced the problem : what is the number of ring isomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}^2$ to $\mathbb{Z}^2$. And I got $6$. After then, I found that if $n=3$, the number is $3! \times 29$. Suddenly, I wondered what is the number of isomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}^n$ to $\mathbb{Z}^n$. I have tried to solve it but failed. What's more, I couldn't find any answers about that on google. Is it easy to solve? I tried to solve the problem by using recursive relation. But it looks difficult.

One of my friends gave me a suggestion to find the number of $n \times n$ invertible matrices with components $1$ or $0$. At first, we thought that it is exactly $(2^n-1)(2^n-2) \dots (2^n-2^{n-1})$. But this equation doesn't work because the construction of the equation discards some cases. For example, $n=3$, the equation discards $ (\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} )$. The equation only works on a finite field. I found that it is a lower bound and upper bound $((n+1)!)^2 2^\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ by a recursive relation. But I don't know until now what is the exact number of that.

+
Due to Perter Franek, I solved it. The answer is $n!$.
Idempotent elements should go idempotent elements and if $\phi$ is an isomorhpism, then $\phi(0)$ implies $0$. The candidates of $e_i=(\delta_{ij})_j$ are each or sum of $\{e_i\}$'s. But if some $e_i$ goes to sum of $e_i's$, $0=\phi(e_i e_j)= \phi(e_i) \phi(e_j) \not =0$ for some $i \not = j$.

Comment: How are you defining an isomorphism?

Comment: ring isomorhpisms. I will add it

Comment: Multiplication is component-wise? Could you please show the $6$, for $n=2$? I can only think of identity and $(x,y)\mapsto (y,x)$.

Comment: Yeap. Component-wise. When $n=2$, $(x, y) \rightarrow (y,x), (x, y) (x, x+y), (x+y, x), (y, x+y), (x+y, y)$ six cases.

Comment: For $(x,y) \mapsto (x, x+y)$, $(1,1)$ (unit) is mapped to $(1,2)$. Is $(1,2)$ a unit?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is not an intergral domain, so we don't need to assume a unit goes a unit.

Comment: Oh, comon, $(1,1)$ times $(0, 100)$ is $(0, 100)$. In the image, is $(1,2)$ times $(0, 100)$ equal to $(0, 100)$?

Comment: It is equal. You can compute it easily. The isomorphisms are totally determined by $e_i=(\delta_{ij})_j$ only $i-th$ component is $1$. So, the candidate of the isomorphisms is a combinations of $\sum (e_i)$'s like $e_1, e_2, e_1+e_2, e_1+e_2+e_3,....$

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something fundamental, but you said that the multiplication is component-wise. So how is it that $(1,2)$ times $(0,100)$ is $(0,100)$ and not $(0, 200)$?

Comment: Let $\phi$ be a map $(x, y) \rightarrow (x, x+y)$. Then $(0, 100)=\phi((0, 100))=\phi((1, 1)(0,100))=\phi((1, 1))\phi((0,100))=(1, 2)(0,100)=(0, 200)$. ooppps, you are right. I am false.

Answer (score 2):

> One of my friends gave me a suggestion to find the number of $n×n$ invertible matrices with components $1$ or $0$.

This is [OEIS A055165](https://oeis.org/A055165); there appears to be no simple formula for it.

Comment: Except the friend's suggestion doesn't actually answer the question correctly.

Comment: I made him confused. At first, I thought that the problem I posed was related to the problem about matrix. But it was not, anyway, this answer also helped me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Any ring homomorphism $\phi$ sends idempotents (elements $e$ satisfying $e^2=1$) to idempotents. The idempotents of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ are the vectors with coordinates all $0$ or $1$. These correspond to subsets of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ (to describe where the $1$s occur in the coordinates). Thus, if $e_1,\cdots,e_n$ refer to the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, there are subsets $A_1,\cdots,A_n\subset\{1,\cdots,n\}$ for which

$$ \phi(e_i)=\sum_{a\in A_{\Large i}}e_a. $$

Moreover, ring homomorphisms preserve zero division. That is, $e_ie_j=0$ (when $i\ne j$) implies

$$ 0=\phi(e_i)\phi(e_j)=\Big(\sum_{a\in A_{\Large i}}e_a\Big)\Big(\sum_{b\in A_{\Large j}} e_{b}\Big)=\sum_{c\in A_{\Large i}\cap A_{\Large j}}e_c.  $$

This implies the $A_1,\cdots,A_n$ are disjoint. They must be nonempty, else $\phi$ would have a kernel, so

$$ n=1+\cdots+1\le |A_1|+\cdots+|A_n|=|A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n|\le n. $$

The only way this inequality is squeezed so tightly is if $|A_i|=1$ for each $i$. Thus, $\phi$ simply permutes the standard basis vectors $e_1,\cdots,e_n$, and there are $n!$ such permutations!

Comment: Thanks. I also solved it after recognizing what I was wrong from the advice of Peter Franek.